# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "rhq_server" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, rhq

I am installed RHQ and try to login the RHQ console, I cant able to login, getting the ERROR in rhq log,.

**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "rhq_server" does not exist**

Installed Postgres by the [guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/PostgreSQL) of RHQ
Getting the below ERROR in postgres

**ERROR:  relation "rhq_server" does not exist at character 519**

Please help me to find the issue,.

Answer (score 1):

Did you connect the DB in the "rhq-server.properties" ?